# Order collection not showing the order that have been invoiced

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, model, invoice, order-collection

I try to retrieve all the order collections, but when I observe by looping the collections and print the order id, I notice the order that has been invoiced is not inside the collection.

```
$collections = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($collections as $collection){
 echo $collection->getId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about that? I tested your code and displays all order ids. Even the invoiced, cancelled, new, processing orders. Actually it displays all the orders. I tested your code in

> app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php -> indexAction()

And when I open the homepage it displays all the orders. I can't figure why you don't get all the ids. Can you test exactly in the same place like me and tell me what displays on your homepage?